# Filter out rows with groupby that are all NaN for a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out rows when groupby `id` when all values in column `a` are NaN. So, across all `id`, if all observations across the dates are NaN, I want to filter the row out. e.g. I want to filter out `id` = 2

**df**

```
            date  id   a    b    c   d
    0   1/1/2000   1  10   20  10.0  11
    1   1/1/2000   2  NaN  21   1.0  11
    2   1/1/2000   3  15   20  14.0  11
    3   1/1/2000   4  NaN  24  13.0  11
    4   1/2/2000   1  10   25  10.0  11
    5   1/2/2000   2  NaN  20  13.0  15
    6   1/2/2000   3  10   26  22.0  11
    7   1/2/2000   4  10   20  16.0  13
    8   1/3/2000   1  10   20  10.0  11
    9   1/3/2000   2  NaN  20  13.0  11
    10  1/3/2000   3  10   20  18.0  11
    11  1/3/2000   4  10   20  10.0  11
```

**desired dataframe**

```
        date  id   a    b    c   d
0   1/1/2000   1  10   20  10.0  11
1   1/1/2000   3  15   20  14.0  11
2   1/1/2000   4  NaN  24  13.0  11
3   1/2/2000   1  10   25  10.0  11
4   1/2/2000   3  10   26  22.0  11
5   1/2/2000   4  10   20  16.0  13
6   1/3/2000   1  10   20  10.0  11
7   1/3/2000   3  10   20  18.0  11
8   1/3/2000   4  10   20  10.0  11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test non missing values by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and then get all groups with at least one match by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html), [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) is used for return `Series` with same size like original, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['a'].notna().groupby(df['id']).transform('any')]
print (df)
        date  id     a   b     c   d
0   1/1/2000   1  10.0  20  10.0  11
2   1/1/2000   3  15.0  20  14.0  11
3   1/1/2000   4   NaN  24  13.0  11
4   1/2/2000   1  10.0  25  10.0  11
6   1/2/2000   3  10.0  26  22.0  11
7   1/2/2000   4  10.0  20  16.0  13
8   1/3/2000   1  10.0  20  10.0  11
10  1/3/2000   3  10.0  20  18.0  11
11  1/3/2000   4  10.0  20  10.0  11
```

Or use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter also `id` with non missisng `a` and then filter original column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `boolean indexing` too:

```
df = df[df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['a'].notna(), 'id'])]
print (df)
        date  id     a   b     c   d
0   1/1/2000   1  10.0  20  10.0  11
2   1/1/2000   3  15.0  20  14.0  11
3   1/1/2000   4   NaN  24  13.0  11
4   1/2/2000   1  10.0  25  10.0  11
6   1/2/2000   3  10.0  26  22.0  11
7   1/2/2000   4  10.0  20  16.0  13
8   1/3/2000   1  10.0  20  10.0  11
10  1/3/2000   3  10.0  20  18.0  11
11  1/3/2000   4  10.0  20  10.0  11
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice not fast as transform but easy to understand

```
out = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x : x['a'].notnull().any())
Out[31]: 
        date  id     a   b     c   d
0   1/1/2000   1  10.0  20  10.0  11
2   1/1/2000   3  15.0  20  14.0  11
3   1/1/2000   4   NaN  24  13.0  11
4   1/2/2000   1  10.0  25  10.0  11
6   1/2/2000   3  10.0  26  22.0  11
7   1/2/2000   4  10.0  20  16.0  13
8   1/3/2000   1  10.0  20  10.0  11
10  1/3/2000   3  10.0  20  18.0  11
11  1/3/2000   4  10.0  20  10.0  11
```